# Building a recursive hierarchy with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have been battling an apparently simple problem for the past couple of hours. I know the solution will use LINQ and recursion but I just cannot get there.

My sample code is below, as is the desired output (something like it, I really do not care, it is building up the hierarchy correctly that is fundamental).

Any help would help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp14
{
    class Program
    {
        static string DoSomething(KeyValuePair<string, string>[] dir)
        {
            return ""; //something here
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            KeyValuePair<string, string>[] dir = new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>(@"c:\one\two\three","100.txt"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>(@"c:\one\two\three","101.txt"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>(@"c:\one\four\five","501.txt"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>(@"c:\one\six\","6.txt"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>(@"c:\one\six","7.txt"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>(@"c:\one\","1.txt"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>(@"c:\one\six\","8.txt"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>(@"c:\one\two","2.txt"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>(@"c:\one\two\three\four\five\six\seven","y.txt"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>(@"c:\one\xxx","xxx.txt")
            };

            // this is the output I want, rough indentation and crlf, the ordering is not important, just the hierarchy
            Console.WriteLine(DoSomething(dir));
            //
            //  one
            //  (1.txt)
            //      two
            //      (2.txt)
            //           three
            //           (100.txt)
            //           (101.txt)
            //               four
            //                    five
            //                        six
            //                             seven
            //                             (y.txt)
            //      four
            //           five
            //           (501.txt)
            //      six
            //      (6.txt)
            //      (7.txt)
            //      (8.txt)
            //      xxx
            //      (xxx.txt)
            //
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I am embarrassed. I had recursion and LINQ and cannot get it to work. I cut down the problem to the basics here. I do not think it is fair that I was down voted.

Comment: Does the order of the output matter to you? Must it match your sample output?

Comment: The order doesn't matter at all, or the indentation. The stumbling block I have is the recursion, although I can easily split up the directory string I just can't seem to get to the final bit.

Answer (score 5):

This is a data structures problem, not an algorithm problem. Once you have the right data structures, the algorithm will be straightforward.

The data structure you need is: a node is either a file or a directory:

```
abstract class Node {}
sealed class Directory : Node {}
sealed class File : Node {}
```

OK, what do we know about a node?  Just that it has a name:

```
abstract class Node 
{
  public string Name { get; private set; }
  public Node(string name) { this.Name = name; }
}
```

What do we know about a file?  Just that it has a name.

```
sealed class File : Node
{
  public File(string name) : base(name) { }
}
```

What do we know about a directory? It has a name and a list of child nodes:

```
sealed class Directory : Node
{
  public Directory(string name) : base(name) { }
  public List<Node> Children { get; } = new List<Node>();
```

We'll want to be able to add a child:

```
  public File WithFile(string name)
  {
    // TODO: Is there already a child that has this name? return it.
    // TODO: Otherwise add it
  }
  public Directory WithDirectory(string name) 
  // TODO: Same.
```

Great, now we can take a directory and add a subdirectory or a file; if one already exists, we get it back.

Now, what is your specific problem?  You have a *sequence of directory names* and a *file name*, and you want to add that file to the directory.  So write that!

```
  public Directory WithDirectory(IEnumerable<string> directories)
  {
    Directory current = this;
    foreach(string d in directories)
      current = current.WithDirectory(d);
    return current;
  }

  public File WithFile(IEnumerable<string> directories, string name)
  {
    return this.WithDirectory(directories).WithFile(name);
  }
```

Now all you have to do is *break up each path into a sequence of names*.  So your algorithm is

```
    Directory root = new Directory("c:");
    foreach(KeyValuePair pair in dir) 
    {
        IEnumerable<string> dirs = TODO break up the key into a sequence of strings
        root.WithFile(dirs, pair.Value);
    }
```

And when you're done **you have a data structure that represents your tree**.

Now that you have a tree, write a method on Node:

```
override string ToString() => this.ToString(0);
string ToString(int indent) 
// TODO can you implement this?
```

The key here is **get the data structure right**.  A directory is just a name plus a list of subdirectories and files, so **write that code**. Once you have the data structure right, the rest follows naturally.  Notice that every method I wrote is only a couple lines long.  (The ones I left as TODOs are similarly very small. Implement them.)  That's what you want:  **do one thing in each method and do it extremely well**.  If you find that you are writing huge long complicated methods, stop and refactor it down into many small methods that each do one clear thing.

EXERCISE:  Implement a version of ToString called ToBoxyString that produces:

```
c:
└─one
  ├─(1.txt)
  ├─two
  │ ├─(2.txt)
  │ └─three
```

... and so on.  It is not as hard as it looks; it's just a fancier indenting.  Can you figure out the pattern?

Comment: Interesting approach. There are surprisingly tricky details to getting this to work properly (e.g. the output isn't supposed to include c:). I went with splitting the paths into components in the `WithDirectories` method.

Comment: @NetMage: The original poster states that the problem is getting the idea of the algorithm, and that the exact details of the output are unimportant. If you don't like a root of "c:" then a root of "" will do just as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using some utility extension methods I like:

```
public static class Ext {
    public static ArraySegment<T> Slice<T>(this T[] src, int start, int? count = null) => (count.HasValue ? new ArraySegment<T>(src, start, count.Value) : new ArraySegment<T>(src, start, src.Length - start));
    public static string Join(this IEnumerable<string> strings, string sep) => String.Join(sep, strings.ToArray());
    public static string Join(this IEnumerable<string> strings, char sep) => String.Join(sep.ToString(), strings.ToArray());
    public static string Repeat(this char ch, int n) => new String(ch, n);
}
```

You can use LINQ to process the paths numerically, which doesn't require any recursion but isn't terribly efficient (it makes a traversal through the original array twice for each depth in the whole tree). The code looks long but it is mostly because I put in lots of comments.

```
static IEnumerable<string> DoSomething(KeyValuePair<string, string>[] dir) {
    char[] PathSeparators = new[] { Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar };
    // some local utility functions
    // split a path into an array of its components [drive,dir1,dir2,...]
    string[] PathComponents(string p) => p.Split(PathSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    // Combine path components back into a canonical path
    string PathCombine(IEnumerable<string> p) => p.Join(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
    // return all distinct paths that are depth deep, truncating longer paths
    IEnumerable<string> PathsAtDepth(IEnumerable<(string Path, string[] Components, string Filename)> dirs, int depth)
        => dirs.Select(pftuple => pftuple.Components)
               .Where(pa => pa.Length > depth)
               .Select(pa => PathCombine(pa.Slice(0, depth + 1)))
               .Distinct();

    // split path into components clean up trailing PathSeparators
    var cleanDirs = dir.Select(kvp => (Path: kvp.Key.TrimEnd(PathSeparators), Components: PathComponents(kvp.Key), Filename: kvp.Value));
    // find the longest path
    var maxDepth = cleanDirs.Select(pftuple => pftuple.Components.Length).Max();
    // ignoring drive, gather all paths at each length and the files beneath them
    var pfl = Enumerable.Range(1, maxDepth)
                        .SelectMany(d => PathsAtDepth(cleanDirs, d) // get paths down to depth d
                             .Select(pathAtDepth => new {
                                Depth = d,
                                Path = pathAtDepth,
                                // gather all filenames for pathAtDepth d
                                Files = cleanDirs.Where(pftuple => pftuple.Path == pathAtDepth)
                                                 .Select(pftuple => pftuple.Filename)
                                                 .ToList()
                            }))
                            .OrderBy(dpef => dpef.Path); // sort into tree
    // convert each entry into its directory path end followed by all files beneath that directory
    var stringTree = pfl.SelectMany(dpf => dpf.Files.Select(f => ' '.Repeat(4 * (dpf.Depth - 1)) + $"({f})")
                                                    .Prepend(' '.Repeat(4 * (dpf.Depth - 1)) + Path.GetFileName(dpf.Path)));

    return stringTree;
}
```

My version of `DoSomething` returns an `IEnumerable<string>` which you can `Join` back into a single string on output if you like:

```
Console.WriteLine(DoSomething(dir).Join(Environment.NewLine));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since my first try was so long, I decided to add this alternative as a separate answer. This version is more efficient as it goes through the dir array once.

Using some extension methods as before:

```
public static class Ext {
    public static ArraySegment<T> Slice<T>(this T[] src, int start, int? count = null) => (count.HasValue ? new ArraySegment<T>(src, start, count.Value) : new ArraySegment<T>(src, start, src.Length - start));
    public static string Join(this IEnumerable<string> strings, string sep) => String.Join(sep, strings.ToArray());
    public static string Join(this IEnumerable<string> strings, char sep) => String.Join(sep.ToString(), strings.ToArray());
    public static string Repeat(this char ch, int n) => new String(ch, n);
}
```

I process the dir array into a `Lookup` which gathers all the files beneath each path. Then I can sort the paths into a tree, and for each path, add the path and the files beneath it. For each subset of the path, I add an empty path entry if it doesn't contain files when converting into a string tree.

```
static IEnumerable<string> DoSomething(KeyValuePair<string, string>[] dir) {
    char[] PathSeparators = new[] { Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar };
    // some local utility functions
    int PathDepth(string p) => p.Count(ch => PathSeparators.Contains(ch));
    string PathToDepth(string p, int d) => p.Split(PathSeparators).Slice(0, d+1).Join(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);

    // gather distinct paths (without trailing separators) and the files beneath them
    var pathsWithFiles = dir.ToLookup(d => d.Key.TrimEnd(PathSeparators), d => d.Value);
    // order paths with files into tree
    var pfl = pathsWithFiles.Select(pfs => new {
                                Path = pfs.Key, // each path
                                Files = pfs.ToList() // the files beneath it
                            })
                            .OrderBy(dpef => dpef.Path); // sort into tree
    // convert each entry into its directory path end followed by all files beneath that directory
    // add entries for each directory that has no files
    var stringTree = pfl.SelectMany(pf => Enumerable.Range(1, PathDepth(pf.Path))
                                                    // find directories without files
                                                    .Where(d => !pathsWithFiles.Contains(PathToDepth(pf.Path, d)))
                                                    // and add an entry for them
                                                    .Select(d => ' '.Repeat(4 * (d-1)) + Path.GetFileName(PathToDepth(pf.Path, d)))
                                                    // then add all the files
                                                    .Concat(pf.Files.Select(f => ' '.Repeat(4 * (PathDepth(pf.Path)- 1)) + $"({f})")
                                                    // and put the top dir first
                                                    .Prepend(' '.Repeat(4 * (PathDepth(pf.Path)-1)) + Path.GetFileName(pf.Path)))
                                                  );

    return stringTree;
}
```

Again you can call it as before:

```
Console.WriteLine(DoSomething(dir).Join(Environment.NewLine));
```